# What does "My duh on" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does "My duh on X" mean?

Does it mean "I like X" or "I don't like X" or something else?

What does "duh" mean in general?

Comment: @Chenmunka I got an email from a US colleague.

Comment: Roger's and Horatio's answers match up with that email I got. Not sure why they were downvoted by other people.

Comment: Never saw this before. More context would help. It may even be a result of autocorrect.

Comment: I've only ever heard of "no duh" being used this way, not "my duh". (As in, "no sh*t, Sherlock": "no duh, idiot, of course the fresh coffee is going to be hot!")

Comment: Could be it was meant to say "My bad on X" and came out mistyped. Like I sad, more context would help.

Answer (score 14):

In this context, I believe it means something like "My mistake; I should have known that."

As @DavidM points out, "Duh" tends to be used to point out the ignorance or obliviousness of a statement as something that should be obvious:

> "Wow, that engine gets hot after running for an hour."
>
> "Well, duh. Of course it does!"

Saying "My duh" would imply that you are acknowledging that something should have been obvious *to you*.

Comment: @Thanks, I think this matches up with what I got in that email.

Answer (score 10):

"My Duh" means "my stupidity" or "my mistake", from what I can tell on my internet search.  "Duh" is the sound we make to sound dumb - see link below for video examples.  I imagine that it is a mashup of "my bad" and "duh".

For example: [Duh moments](http://youtu.be/rS401CI7TZg)

Comment: This seems reasonable.  I just didn't wish to step out on the limb of defining a statement I haven't heard.

Comment: Your answer is good too @DavidM, because the OP asked what "Duh" means, in general. :-)

Answer (score 8):

"Duh" is a word that represents a sub-vocalization. It usually is used on its own to suggest that the other person has said something stupid.

"My bad" is an idiom which means roughly: "That was bad, I did it, and I take responsibility."

"My duh on that" *probably* means the speaker is saying: "That was stupid, I did it, and I recognize that."

Comment: @Thanks, I think this matches up with what I got in that email.

Comment: I agree with this interpretation. I am no language expert here, but I am a native US-English speaker. "My Duh" isn't something that I have heard, and sounds like a person's own variation of another slang phrase "My bad", which is to admit to something being your fault. I would interpret somebody saying "my duh" to mean that they are acknowledging a misunderstanding to have been theirs and not yours. It essentially meaning the same thing but perhaps with an additional (slang) nuance on how they chose to express it.

Answer (score 3):

I've never encountered the term "My duh on ..."

[Duh](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duh), in general, is a sound that is made to imply derision or feigned ignorance about the perceived stupidity or obviousness of a statement.

In other words, to say "You really don't understand something as simple as that?"  It's mild, but impolite.

Example of usage:

> "We really should have bought our tickets to the movie before it sold out!"
>   "Duh!?! You think?!?"